# How to search a Windows DNS server tree for a specific SRV service?

Tags: c, windows, dns, srv

Our customers add a unique service (_careq) with an SRV record to their DNS servers so our software can just do a DnsQuery lookup and get the host's name.

The problem is some customers don't put the SRV record in the correct location (it should read _careq._tcp.[FQDN], but customers can put it in _careq._tcp.[subdomain].[FQDN], etc).

Rather than fixing every customer's DNS server, is there a way to just send a query to the DNS server with our service name (_careq) and have it search its entire DNS tree?

If not, is there another/better way to do a DNS lookup for our host server?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't get there from here.**

DNS does not publish a list of subdomains.  *Game Over*.

Well, "game over"  unless they have *zone transfers* enabled for your client and that is fairly unlikely.

As for an alternative:  perhaps **zeroconf**  can do what you want.